# print layer and vertex of DXF file in python

Tags: python, layer, vertex, dxf, ezdxf

I try to display layers (Sew Lines and Pattern Perimeter) from a dxf file.
As a matter of fact, some points of these layers are exactly at the same place : so I wan't to remove some points of one of these layers.
To do this I have to access layers, and then vertex to have coordinates.

Someone has already do this exercise or have an idea to help me?

Thank you,
Mary

I wan't to delete some points

Comment: I succeeded to display layers: for layer in dxf.layers:
    print(layer.dxf.name). How can I access to vertex I want to delete?

Comment: Glad you made it work. Please post your solution as an answer so others can benefit from it. Please create a new question for your follow up question. Sharing some code will help others to understand your problem. Welcome to SO.

Comment: for layer in dxf.layers:
    print(layer.dxf.name)

Comment: you posted a *comment*, not an *answer*. The way this site works, there's a major difference between the two. See also the [help on self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Please scroll down to the textbox with "Your Answer" written above it. Post your answer there, explain what it does and why it works. You will have to wait for two days before you can accept your own answer. Thank you very much!